# How do I pass the size of an array at runtime?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I thought the following code snippet might run.

```
public class Stack {
    int n;
    char arr[]=new char[n];
    int top=0;

    void Push(char val) {
        arr[top]=val;
        top++;   
    }
}

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack obj=new Stack();
        obj.n=5;
        obj.Push('a');
        obj.Push('a');
        obj.Push('a');
        obj.Push('a');
    }
}
```

However it gives an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Why isn't the size of array changing to 5?

Comment: Because you do `new char[n]` before `n` has been set to `5`. In other words, `n` is zero when you create the array

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor for your stack. By default `n` value is set to zero. So, your array is being created with 0 size. Paramertized constructor like below should do the job for you.

```
      public class Stack {
        int n;
        char arr[];
        int top=0;

        public Stack(int n) {
            this.n = n;
            this.arr = new char[n];
        }

    }
```